# How to charge a 3.7 V Li-ion cell with a 2S BMS?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I have only a 5 V charger and a 3.7 V Li-ion battery and a 2S BMS.

How can I extract the cable to connect to the (BM) port on the 2S BMS?

Comment: You need a proper Li ion battery charger. A BMS isn't a charger.

Answer (score 4):

> I have only a 5v charger

That is not a 5 V charger. That is a 5 V power supply (a.k.a. AC adapter).

A power supply is not a charger. And a BMS is not a charger either.

- Power supply: regulates voltage (not current)
- Charger: limits both the voltage and the current to what the battery needs at a given moment.
- BMS: off/on, no regulation

> a 2s bms

You cannot use a 2S BMS to protect a single cell.

> How can i  ..

1. Set the 5 V AC adapter aside
2. Set the 2S BMS aside
3. Buy a charger for a single Li-ion cell
4. Buy a 1S BMS (for a single Li-ion cell)
5. Connect the cell to the 1S BMS
6. Connect the charger to the BMS

Comment: NB: This is "just another member" comment. No official hat worn. || You edited a question of mine re LiIon cell swapping. Thanks. Legitimately changing typos and presentation are fine. Please do not remove technical content. At a munimum if you must do so then a comment to me (or others) on changes to their technical contemt is suggested.

Comment: +1. Comment only: It's likely that a 2 cell BMS can be adapted to protect 1 cell. The effort of doing so and knowledge rquired are outside the OP's ability. (I know you know that :-).)